# How to debug tomcat start up stuck because of some listener added

Tags: tomcat

I need to start one class on tomcat start up, i added following lines in ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<listener>
   <listener-class>com.listener.InitListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

InitListener.java internally start some thread's(two to three), i copied all the jar files needed for this calss in WEB-INF/lib, when i restart tomcat i am getting SOP of constructor in catalina.out.
 But,however,tomcat is not starting further,it stuck there,no exception's nothing. 
Please tell me how to debug this issue? 

**Working environment**

> **OS**:linux 64bit 
>    **Tomcat**: apache-tomcat-7.0.52

Comment: That could be anything. You need to post the relevant part of the stack trace.

Comment: Thank u stefan, i found issue, The listener internally creating one socket connection then it is waiting to accept request(here it get stuck)

Answer (score 0):

A socket will block until it receives a request. You can create a thread (or better a fixed thread pool, size 1) to handle connections . But do you really have to rely on a plain socket? There are dozens of ways to handle data transfer better, ie: Servlets, MVC frameworks, RMI, Webservice, REST resources, ...

Comment: Thank u stefan i created that listener as thread, it is working fine.Yes We rely on plain socket.we are planning to change the design.